# Cannot get position from iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm trying to get position by using iOS simulator by simple swift code.  But In debugging session, callback function is not called. I set virtual position to iOS simulator.

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  helloWorld
//
//  Created by  on 5/17/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015   All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locMan: CLLocationManager!
    var lat: CLLocationDegrees!
    var lng: CLLocationDegrees!
    var hasPosData: Bool

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        locMan  = CLLocationManager()
        lat = CLLocationDegrees()
        lng = CLLocationDegrees()
        hasPosData = false
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func retreiveCurrentPos(){
        locMan.delegate = self
        locMan.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // start using GPS function
        locMan.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func saveResult2File(){
        var contents: String

        let dirToSave = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as! Array<String>
        let file      = String(dirToSave[0]) + "pos.dat"
        if(hasPosData){
            contents = String(format:"lat: %f lng: %f", lat, lng)
        }else{
            contents = "Failed to retreive position data"
        }

        contents.writeToFile(file, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        retreiveCurrentPos()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
        lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude
        lng = newLocation.coordinate.longitude
        hasPosData = true
        saveResult2File()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        hasPosData = false
        saveResult2File()
    }
}
```

Comment: question: you are trying to get the position of... what exactly?

Comment: instead of adding dummy paragraphs to make the post longer, you should explain the problem more, and maybe say something about GPS or such...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set a location in your iOS simulator, it is by default set to none what make the app crash as you didn't check it before use.
Also you need to add a key in the pList NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, just in case you forgot.

[image]

plist

[image]

Comment: In iOS8,it is required to add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key value pair to Info.plist file.

Comment: I set location in my iOS simulator. And I add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key to pList. But callback function is not called.

Comment: I notice you didn't setup the accuracy, maybe this is the problem try add locMan.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest, just after you set the delegate to self. Let me know if it work for you.

Comment: Thank you for valiant advice. I can get  latitude and longitude.